# Setting up specific page redirects as well as entire site redirects in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to setup a redirect on my site to go to a different domain which I am able to do so with this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great but there are also a few pages that I want to completely change the url as well as redirect to the new domain. Here is an example:

1.) Here is an example url to my old domain. https://www.olddomain.com/product-tag/**[tag-name]**/. I want this go to https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=**[tag-name]**/.

2.) Here is an example url to my old domain. https://www.olddomain.com/product-categories/**[category-name]**/garbage. I want this go to https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=**[category-name]**/.

I was hoping that adding something like this would do the trick but it does not seem to be working:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/product-tag/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# handle both specific URL redirects    
RewriteRule ^/?product-(?:tag|categories)/([\w-]+) https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I just tested the "specific URL redirects" and still seems to not be redirecting correctly.  I am still just being sent to the newdomain. I tested on my domain and it is not working as well at this testing tool i found online http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: I had a typo that I just fixed. You must clear your browser cache before testing. Above rules work fine on my Apache

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the help.